# Is there any way to convert html template to liferay theme?

Tags: themes, liferay

Is there any way to convert html template to Liferay 6.2 theme ? Is Alloy UI help me about this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "one-click" tool to convert an html template to a liferay theme. You have to implement the theme yourself and use the "diff" folder to configure your own custom templates (.vm), scripts (.js) and styles (.css). Check out the official docs:

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-themes-and-layout-templates-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Artem's answer which gives you the correct answer to your question. As a "no" might not be what you were looking for, let me add some reasoning extra - why would such a tool be introducing even more work later in the game?

If you look at the basic structure of Liferay's HTML code - all the nested divs, classes and ids - you'll find that they're quite clean and structured. A lot of Liferay's functionality is implemented with this kind of DOM in mind. If you'd introduce your own, completely unrelated, DOM from your own template, you'd need to find all components in Liferay that assume a certain structure. For example Layout Templates: They define "drop zones" where you can add portlets to the page. You probably don't have them in your existing templates. Another example: Maximized portlets. They'll need a DOM element to go into.

IMHO you're a lot better of to stick very close to the original DOM and just tweak your CSS to address the classes/elements you need. This is, of course, just a very general recommendation - for certain usecases this approach might also be a disadvantage. But most of the standard usecases are covered IMHO